# Django - HELP!! Media images won't appear on the template screen

Tags: django

I need help with making images uploaded by users to appear on templates. I've been doing every solutions that I could find, but they all left me with nothing but broken images on the screen.

The framework I'm currently using is Django and here are the codes consisting the program. I can upload other codes as well if requested. 'avatar' is the name for the profile image.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('movies:home')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('movies:home')
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request,'accounts/forms.html',context)
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"Sorry! This nickname is already in use TT"})
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email',max_length=255, unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"This email is already in use XD"})
    description = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images', blank=True)
```

profile.html  => this is the template where users can see their own profiles as well as others'

If a user had not uploaded any images to be set as their profile image, an image file that I had prepared in a static folder is set as their default image

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.avatar %}
    <img src="{{ user.avatar.url }}" height="300" width="240">
{% else %}
    <img src="../../../../static/base_img.jpg" height="300" width="240">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What's the url for the broken image?

Comment: the url  shown on elements is <img src="/media/images/testimg.jpg" height="300" width="240">

Comment: Does that file exist at MEDIA_ROOT? Is this on production or development?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out! The problem was that I put the ```+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)``` code at the end of the urlpatterns of movie app's urls.py, instead of urls.py of the whole project. Very stupid of me indeed :p

Comment: Sounds like the usual new django dev hiccups. You're in good company.